# Como inspeccionar la duración que se toma en cada linea de codigo

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy usando visual studio 2012, necesito inspeccionar la duracion que se toma al ejecutar o reccorrer cada linea de codigo, he buscado y no logro encontrarlo, conocen alguna forma de hacerlo?. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Depurar tu codigo

Comment: Lo hice, pero no encuentro algo que diga Duracion o Tiempo algo.

Comment: A mi cada vez que le doy a f11 debajo de la linea de código me dice el tiempo que duró si no te aparece debes ver si puedes agregarlo por la configuración de IDE

Comment: Puedes usar si no [`StopWatch`](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez creo en mi VS 2012 no tiene esa caracteristica :/